# Is there any Component for sql database process different from ADONET?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Can I use another data access component different from ADO.Net in visual studio.net ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ADO.NET? Because different people interpret that in different ways... some people mean just the core data access (DbCommand, DbDataReader etc); some people mean the whole DataTable/DataSet ugliness... please clarify

Comment: See here, how to use ODBC from .NET: note that System.Data is still referenced so it's more about the comment from Marc above, what do we mean by ADO.NET... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310985

Comment: @Davide which is an ADO.NET provider for ODBC, so still ADO.NET ;p (this isn't a criticism of you, Davide; the OP ***really*** needs to clarify things here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.NET has different meanings to different people; if you mean the "core" ADO.NET services, i.e. the provision of a connection/command/parameter/reader, then for a *database* implementation you might struggle - but *why* would you want to use a completely separate stack? ADO.NET fulfils that role admirably.

If, by ADO.NET, you mean data-set, data-table, data-adapter etc; then indeed - don't use that stuff ;p Whether you use an ORM, a micro-ORM, or whatever else - yes, there are ***lots*** of tools that can give you a better experience of loading your data, without using DataTable.

If you aren't using a RDBMS, then the world is your mollusc; any number of nosql connectors are around; please be specific and people will help.

The choice of *which* tool to use is a: dependent on what you want to do, and b: somewhat subjective - so you'll notice I haven't mentioned any *specific* tools. The question is too much like walking into a hardware store and saying "I need a tool, but I don't want to use a spanner"...

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to really answer your question with no reasons why you want to do it.

in my opinion as long as you do not reference

```
Syste.Data.*
```

in your project, you are not using ADO.NET.

if you want to connect to a database of another vendor which gives you a custom implementation of everything ( connection wrappers, data containers etc etc ) then you connect using their assemblies and not ADO.NET

not sure about the way ODBC is handled, in theory you can create anything from scratch meaning you can use System.IO and access to the disk at byte level and read what you need, not sure this is the best way to go.